# Set a condition when set of rows (not all) repeats itself in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

IF account_no > ‘10000000’ and  offset_account = ‘6XXX’ 
THEN 
If the value of the columns --- (security_no AND asofdate AND abs(qty)) occurs again in the table 
THEN (1)
ELSE (0).

```
sub_no account_no rep security_no symbol asofdate abs_qty new_column
177    12345      X   2000        A      20180101 100     1
177    23456      Y   2000        A      20180101 100     1
177    34567      Z   5000        A      20180101 300     0
177    45455      Z   5000        A      20170909 300     0
```

The first row should have the value 1 as  values under security_no, asofdate and abs_qty columns are exactly same as that of row 2.

The second row should have the value 1 as  values under security_no, asofdate and abs_qty columns are exactly same as that of row 1.

The third row should have the value 0 as  values under security_no, asofdate and abs_qty columns are not same as any other rows in the table.

The fourth row should have the value 0 as values under security_no, asofdate and abs_qty columns are not same as any other rows in the table.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first row" or "second row" in a table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Please specify what column or combinations of columns are used to define the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do what you want using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by security_no, asofdate, abs_qty) > 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as new_column
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. This solution works like a charm.